# Rake aborted - Unable to find platform. How to resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, terminal

when I try to install my Ruby on Rails App, exactly when I digit:

`sudo rake db:migrate`

terminal returns to me:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Unable to find Platform
/Users/ladmin/Sites/IkarosGest/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:17
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/ladmin/Sites/IkarosGest/vendor/plugins/wicked_pdf/init.rb:1:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/ladmin/Sites/IkarosGest/config/environment.rb:6
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: Why not tell us your Ruby version, RubyGems version and the gem that is reporting an error?

Comment: Ruby version: 1.8.7    RubyGems: 1.3.7 and ehm I don't which is the gem

Comment: You may need to add `--platform=ruby` when install gems. http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#platform . Also you need wkhtmltopdf according to <https://github.com/astjohn/wicked_pdf>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it! The problem was in "wickedpdf.rb" in this piece of code:

```
  if Platform.is_windows?
   include Win32PdfRenderer
  elsif Platform.is_linux?
   include NixPdfRenderer
  else
   raise "Unable to find Platform"
  end
```

because I'm on Mac :D

Comment: did you just comment that line or did you include something for the mac platform to resolve the problem?

Comment: @HendraUzia you're [installing](http://projectfedena.org/forum/11-rails-gems-and-plugins/topics/402-unable-to-find-platform-mac) fedena right? I simply put `include NixPdfRenderer` under the else.. and all is good.. (usually with these kind of setup/hello world problems.. it's best just to get the thing up and running.. then once you're comfortable with the code.. you can go back and see why the pdf rendering is acting out etc.. just get your 'hello world' going)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sudo` for `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?